# Opencart, Javascript file common,js uneditable?

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, opencart

I am running on **version 1.5.5.1** of **opencart**, and for some odd reasons, if i try to change the `common.js` file located in `(/catalog/view/javascript/common.js)`, it is never taken in consideration or my code is burnt down like if it never existed. I tried renaming the file, name stayed the same, but the browser kept on loading the old file that doesnt exist anymore on the server `XD` (and i opened a fresh new browser to test that, so i dont have anything in cache or whatever else).

So i was wondering if someone would know anything about this problem and/or to solve it !

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your server is set up and if it's setting far future expires for files like javascript, css etc.

I don't know anything about XD servers, but under Apache I run a very complex .htaccess rule set that caches just about everything, it's based on the .htaccess file included with [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess)

Not knowing which browser you're using, one thing from your question that stands out is that opening a new window isn't going to clear your cache, you need to manually do that.

I have this problem occasionally and clearing the cache usually takes care of it.

One good way I've found os to increment your js and css files dynamically and edit the number when you make a change. In that .htaccess file you'll see a section for cache busting, you may need to adjust that if you're not using Apache.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Filename-based cache busting                                               |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# If you're not using a build process to manage your filename version revving,
# you might want to consider enabling the following directives to route all
# requests such as `/css/style.12345.css` to `/css/style.css`.

# To understand why this is important and a better idea than `*.css?v231`, read:
# http://stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
# </IfModule>
```

Hope this helps you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

There may be file permission issue. Sometimes when you upload or transfer, or even extract files from an archive, you may need to look into file permissions or fixing of file ownership. Another case, you may have ran out of disk space on server, which won't allow to replace file with a new one.